# I can't capture multiple form and list javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm having trouble doing a function in javascript
like she takes the form data and lists it below
I'm doing it this way

```
<pre>

> function changeText2 () {
>         var assembly = ['staff', 'description']
>         var node = document.createElement ("LI");
>         var textnode = document.createTextNode (assembly);
>         node.appendChild (textnode);

 document.getElementById ("demo"). appendChild (node);
     </pre>
```

only it returns only ids "staff" and "description"

I want you to take several input
An example
what pretty much what I want you to do is this

only with several campuses

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to something like this below. Don't forget to modify HTML accordingly as written in JSfiddle link

```
const list = document.getElementById('demo');

  const changeText2= () => {
         let staff = document.getElementById('staff').value;
         let desc = document.getElementById('desc').value;

         let node = document.createElement ("LI");
         let textnode = document.createTextNode(`${staff}, ${desc}`);
         node.appendChild (textnode);
 document.getElementById ("demo"). appendChild (node);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gjs789f/

To expand on your code, first you didn't specify whether you want inputs taken from the fields specified within HTML DOM. You do that by separately calling getElementById on specific fields (in this case, 'staff' and 'desc', as per your code example) and call .value function on them to get the value from the fields.

After that, configure the text that will be displayed inside the LI element.

Using `` and ${} constructions of ES6 as in my example its quite easy, but you can as well use the example below if you find it easier. I may argue it's indeed easier on the eyes, even though I prefer ES6 way.

```
let textnode = document.createTextNode(staff + ", " + desc);
```

Finally, append the text node, then append the li element. Done.